# GWT + AppEngine

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, gwt

I have been trying to create a project with the latest version of GWT (2.8.1), AppEngine (1.9.54) and Objectify (5.1.21) using Eclipse and Maven without success.

I can't find recent documentation or tutorial showing how to use GWT and AppEngine together. Is there a working, out of the box sample project I could base my project on?

Also, what is the correct way to launch my project; using GWT Super Dev Mode, using Run on App Engine or is it something else?

Comment: new web app project then check Use GWT

Comment: I am facing the same difficulties. Did you get the Eclipse+GWT+App Engine setup to work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this pom as example:

https://gist.github.com/slugmandrew/6687120

or maybe this project:

https://github.com/branflake2267/Archetypes/tree/master/archetypes/appengine-endpoints-guice-objectify

Answer (score 0):

Use *Run on App Engine*, but you'll need to [enable the *GWT SDM Builder*](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/migrating-gpe).